# Close server (socket) when custom error occures

Tags: c, sockets

I am writing a simple client server program with c sockets. I used the code from http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/socket_server_example.htm Now I am trying to extend the code, namely when I have multiple clients I check if a custom error occures in my doprocessing function and if that is the case, I want to stop the server, but I dont know how?

```
// Setup socket, works
for(;;) {   
    ConnectFD = accept(SocketFD, (struct sockaddr*) &cli_addr, (socklen_t*)&clilen);

    if (pid == -1) {
        perror("Error: Fork");
        close(SocketFD);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if (pid == 0) {
        close(SocketFD);
        error = doprocessing(ConnectFD);
        if (error == 1) {
            // Stop the server
        }
        exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    } else {
        close(ConnectFD);
    }
}
return 0;
```

So i check for the error and if the error is 1 i want to shut down the server, but I really cant figure out how to do that.

Best reagrds

Comment: When you say "shut down the server" do you mean exit the program or shut down the actual computer?

Comment: Yeah, your code atm will exit the server process no matter what `error` is.

Comment: Not sure if this is a good idea. A malicious use could shutdown your server.

Comment: I am open for improvements :)

Answer (score 0):

A little unclear what you're asking here. If you just want the child server that handled the bad request to shutdown, you simply need to have it call `exit()`:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    close(SocketFD);
    error = doprocessing(ConnectFD);
    if (error == 1) {
        // Stop the server
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

But I suspect that you knew that, and maybe you're saying you want it to shut down the parent server from the child? If so, and you're on a UNIX/Linux type system, you can get the parent's process id with the `getppid(2)` system call and then send it a `SIGTERM` signal telling it to shutdown. e.g.:

```
if (pid == 0) {
    close(SocketFD);
    error = doprocessing(ConnectFD);
    if (error == 1) {
        /* Find the parent server */
        pid_t parent = getppid();
        /* Stop the parent server */
        kill(parent, SIGTERM);
        /* And stop the child */
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
```

Comment: I mean I want the server stop running in the console. Your code does exactly what I want, I didn't think about this way to kill the pid, I thought there might be a way to close the socket with close() or shutdown() or something, but I think there isn't?

Comment: Calling close() in the child will only close the child's copy of the file descriptor. The parent would continue unaffected. If you want to do cleanup in the parent before it shuts down, you can set a signal handler for SIGTERM in the parent, so that when the signal arrives, a function you designated will run at that time which can cleanup. See: `int sigaction(int signum, const struct sigaction *act, struct sigaction *oldact);`  Call that in the parent during startup, and pass your cleanup routine as `act->sa_handler`.